# SQL Server selects inefficient execution plan

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a replicated SQL Server used exclusively for reporting of debit/credit card transactions.

This server is a subscriber from the OLTP DB. This has a transaction table that is populated almost every second from new transaction records happening in prod OLTP.

Now, I run the following query against my replicated transaction table, the result set has 13,00,000 records and the query took 45 minutes to execute.

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, col3...., col25
FROM 
    [dbo].TRANSACTION_MAIN WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE   
    XACTIONDATE BETWEEN ('2017-06-01 00:00:00.000') AND ('2017-06-30 11:59:59.997') 
    AND CLIENTID IN (999) 
    AND RETURNCODE = 32 
    AND SUCCESSCODE > '99' 
    AND STATUSID = 999 
    AND XACTIONTYPEID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
```

I have another env. which is the EOD back up of PROD OLTP. If I run the same query there it gives me same amount of data in just 2 minutes.

Indexes: the table has a non-unique nonclustered index on `XACTIONDATE`. The clustered index is on an identity column of the table.

When I checked the execution plan on the EOD Bkp DB, I see that it is using this index and is doing an index seek (key look to clustered index)  to pull data.

When I checked the execution plan on the live replication DB I see that it does not do an index seek, but does an index scan. No key look up happens here.

I then used query hint FORCESEEK in SQL query in live replication DB I get results in 2 minutes.

So earlier it was taking 45 minutes just because SQL Server is using an inefficient execution plan.

Why is SQL Server not using the correct index in the execution plan, what could be possible reasons for it?

Thanks,
Roopesh

Comment: Have you checked and if needed updated your **statistics**?

Comment: Hi Marc, yes statistics are set to AutoUpdate on the server

Comment: Don't rely only on auto-updating statistics - if you have this kind of odd behavior, **manually** update your statistics and see if it makes any difference!

Comment: Will try it out and post an update here. Thanks for your suggestions Marc.

Comment: Hello, apologies for a late response. We tried this as well. Updated statistics, basically we rebuild all indexes and ran the same query again. It is still using the incorrect execution plan. Our team is still trying out options to make it perform better. Any suggestions here is appreciated.